# C++ Taking the Base Class as an Input and Accessing Derived Class Member Functions

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Say I have defined 2 classes, a base class and a derived class. Then I write a function that takes the base class as an input.
When I use that function I will only ever pass in derived class functions and want to be able to access a redefined version of a base class method.
So lets say both the base and derived class have a method foo(). I create a derived class variable and pass it into a function that only accepts base class variables. Inside that function I want to access foo() as it is defined in the derived class, not as it is defined in the base class.
I have tried protected but that doesn't work.

Comment: a simple example would work wonders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the function `virtual` and that will access the derived class implementation on a base class pointer if the pointer points to a derived class instance.

Make sure you are passing a pointer or a reference (NOT passing the object by value)

Comment: Just to clarify, it's important to pass a pointer (a reference would work too), not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseT
{
    public: virtual void f(string msg) { cout << msg << " from Base" << endl; }
};

class DerivedT: public BaseT
{
    public: void f(string msg) { cout << msg << " from Derived" << endl; }
};

// myFunc says hi from derived or from base
// depending on what b really points to

void myFunc (BaseT *b) { b->f("hi"); }  

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    DerivedT d;
    BaseT b;

    myFunc (&d);
    myFunc (&b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is going to leak because you are not calling `delete` on the memory allocated in each parameter.  This is NOT C# or managed C++ !

Comment: I'm not sure what runtime you use but mine returns the prog's heap to the OS upon exit. I tried to focus on the issue.

Comment: Leaking memory is a bad practice - even if the OS cleans it up it is a poor habit to get into.

Comment: It's one of my lesser bad habits.

Comment: Just to prevent from getting downvotes, stick `delete b;` in `myFunc` right after `b->f("hi");` I would edit the post for you but I feel like that'd be intrusion on my behalf.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Yeah ok, I crossed a red light with children AND nannies watching... dunno what's worse. Feel free to edit though, next time. But I think calling delete on pointers passed into functions is REALLY mean ;-) !